# Which SQL Server lock should I use

Tags: sql-server, locking

Newbie question here. After reading many articles about SQL Server locks, I am still confused.

Here is my case scenario.

1. I need to read a table row (more specifically a numeric value in this row).
2. Then I need to send this numeric value to a service through an API request and wait for the response.
3. If the response is positive, I need to increment the numeric value and update the row. If negative, nothing needs to be done.
4. While this occurs, I don't want other requests to be able to neither read nor modify the row.

I've read I should use `XLOCK` with `ROWLOCK`...

1. Is this correct?
2. What happens with the other requests that could occur while the lock is in place? Do they fail and need to be retried or do they wait?

Comment: You could use a db lock, but it's not a good idea to hold it for so long. Better to implement the lock on the frontend side (per row id)

Comment: You need to (obviously) wrap your process in a transaction and use a locking hint on your select ie `with(holdlock, updlock)` - this will *block* any other process from touching the row until you commit or roll back. holding a transaction open waiting on an external API call though is probably not wise, and this would presumably be a distributed transaction started in the application. you could implement RCSI isolation which would allow other processes to always see the value before the transaction started, if that's desirable.

Comment: I agree this sounds like a really bad idea to hold a lock for so long. You need to use some kind of front-end lock, for example setting a `LockedBy` column